# Converting newly created angular cli project to use mocha framework instead of jasmine

Tags: angular, mocha.js, angular-cli, karma-mocha, karma-chrome-launcher

Hey i created a new project with latest angular cli. It creates a project that uses jasmine as the testing framework. I wanted to use mocha.

I added the required plugins following the project 
https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/blob/master/karma.conf.js

I get the following error when running test using command ng test[image]

Has anybody faced an error or is there a way to figure out what is generating this issue.

Answer (score 5):

## The Problem

`zone.js` uses a handful of "patches" when it is used in a test environment. For convenience, `zone.js` provides a single module that bundles all those patches together. That module is `zone.js/dist/zone-testing`. This is the package that `@angular/cli` uses in the test setup, it is imported in `src/test.ts`. The problem is that `zone.js/dist/zone-testing` assumes you are using jasmine and includes a jasmine patch. The jasmine patch is what is causing your error.

## The Fix

To fix it, you just have to import each of the patches yourself instead of using the convenience, prepackaged module. In `src/test.ts`

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
```

needs to become

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/mocha-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-promise-test';
```

These are the exact same packages that `zone.js/dist/zone-testing` uses; however, it is importing the `mocha-patch` instead of the `jasmine-patch`.